# Proguard with instant apps. How to have one defined proguard file applied to all features

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

As instant app features are compiled into seperate APKs the proguard step becomes a little bit more tricky.
For example you can no longer just have one proguard file defined in the runnable module and let it obsfuscate all features. Every feature must have its own proguard. 
I would like to know how you can easily define one proguard file and use some gradle magic to apply them to all feature modules?
Having multiple proguard files in each module is just unmaintainable.

Comment: Check out these posts about proguard usage across multi-library projects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820915/android-studio-proguard-handling-in-multi-library-projects/31031491#31031491,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783407/proguard-also-use-proguard-files-from-modules

Comment: @Gillis Haasnoot, i hope you problems has been solved with above comment.